# How to create an array to hold structures?

Tags: c#, arrays, structure

I was asked to create some structures: student, teacher, course, program
and then make an array to hold 5 students structures, and assign values to the fields of students in the array, I'm stuck in creating the array to hold the structures, here is the code:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace Module4Assignment
{
    class Program
    {
        //Student structure: 
        public struct Student
        {
            public Student (string name , string address , string country , string birthday , int telephone)
            {
                this.Name = name;
                this.Address = address;
                this.Country = country;
                this.Birthday = birthday;
                this.Telephone =telephone;
            }

            public string Name;
            public string Address;
            public string Country;
            public string Birthday;
            public int Telephone;
        }

        //Teacher structure:
        public struct Teacher
        {
            public Teacher(string tname, string taddress, string tcountry, string tbirthday, int ttelephone)
            {
                this.TName = tname;
                this.TAddress = taddress;
                this.TCountry = tcountry;
                this.TBirthday = tbirthday;
                this.TTelephone = ttelephone;
            }

            public string TName;
            public string TAddress;
            public string TCountry;
            public string TBirthday;
            public int TTelephone;
        }

        //Program structure
        public struct Program
        {
            public Program(string pname , string department , int pcredits)
            {
                this.PName = pname;
                this.Department = department;
                this.PCredits = pcredits;

            }
            public string PName;
            public string Department;
            public int PCredits;
        }

        //Course structure
        public struct Course
        {
            public Course(string cname, string day, int ccredits)
            {
                this.CName = cname;
                this.Day = day;
                this.CCredits = ccredits;

            }
            public string CName;
            public string Day;
            public int CCredits;
        }


        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            //Instantiating 5 students structures:
            Student student1 = new Student();
            Student student2 = new Student();
            Student student3 = new Student();
            Student student4 = new Student();
            Student student5 = new Student();


            //creating the array:
            string[] studentArray = new string[5];
            studentArray[0]=student1;
            studentArray[1]=student2;
            studentArray[2]=student3;
            studentArray[3]=student4;
            studentArray[4]=student5;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Don't use a struct. Use a class. There is no reason for you to be using a struct here.

Comment: @vcsjones You need to look at the namespace `Module4Assignment` :)

Comment: it's not my choice , it's an assigments on structres and arrays

Comment: This kind of questions makes me want to hurt your teacher. `string[]` is an array of strings. you need to use `Student[]`. can you see the difference?

Comment: Show your teacher this: [Mutating Readonly Structs](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2008/05/14/mutating-readonly-structs.aspx)

Comment: all the class want to hurt him xD , yeah thanks buddy.

Comment: To be fair, its a free online course, not one where an actual teacher is going out of his/her way to help students.  Its a general Intro to C# course that says different classes are more of the way to go but wants us to understand that Structs can also be useful before they teach us about adding Classes in depth.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I have a lot of problems with what you're doing here, but the simple answer is that you cant put Student objects into an array of strings:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        //Instantiating 5 students structures :
        Student student1 = new Student();
        Student student2 = new Student();
        Student student3 = new Student();
        Student student4 = new Student();
        Student student5 = new Student();


        //creating the array :
        Student [] studentArray = new Student[5]; // <---- array of Student!
        studentArray[0]=student1;
        studentArray[1]=student2;
        studentArray[2]=student3;
        studentArray[3]=student4;
        studentArray[4]=student5;
    }
```

Answer (score 4):

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    Student[] studentArray = new Student[5];
}
```

That's it. You do not need to explicitly create and assign the elements, because `Student` is a struct (value type).

Answer (score 1):

what you did on the code above is a repetition of just creating an array of a structure because you are supposed to create 5 structures with the properties of the original structure so you should do it like this

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;

namespace EDXonline_AssignmentFour
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {

            student[] studentArray = new student[5];
            studentArray[0].FirstName = "einstein";
            studentArray[0].LastName = "makuyana";
             DateTime date1 = new DateTime(1993, 11, 22, 02, 00, 0);
             studentArray[0].Birthdate = date1;


            Console.WriteLine("student First Name: {0}", studentArray[0].FirstName);
            Console.WriteLine("student Last Name: {0}", studentArray[0].LastName);
            Console.WriteLine("student birthday: {0}", studentArray[0].Birthdate.ToString());

            Console.ReadKey();

        }

        public struct student
        {
            // This is the custom constructor.
            public student(string firstname, string lastname, DateTime birthdate)
               {
                  this.FirstName = firstname;
                  this.LastName = lastname;
                  this.Birthdate = birthdate;
               }
               // These statements declare the struct fields and set the default values.
               public string FirstName;
               public string LastName;
               public DateTime Birthdate;
        }
```